# How to mock DynamodbContext BatchWrite for unit testing in net

Tags: c#, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, nunit

I have a method that adds Items in the DynamoDb table using DynamoDbContext.

```
var batchWriteObj = context.CreateBatchWrite<myDynamoDBModel>
                                            (new DynamoDBOperationConfig { TableNamePrefix = "abc" });
                    batchWriteObj.AddPutItem(myDynamoDBModel);
```

I want to test this piece in my Unit test.
Since BatchWrite does not have any constructor, and also its properties are not virtual. I am unable to create a mock for it.

Is there any way I can test this piece of code? maybe by mocking the BatchWrite?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using DynamoDB local to run tests? It has the added advantage of validating that your calls are doing what you expect them to do. I created a helper package for it a while back (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Wadsworth.DynamoDB.TestUtilities/). It just manages spinning up the DynamoDB local in a Docker container. You can see the source for it [here](https://github.com/jasonwadsworth/DotNet.DynamoDB.TestUtilities), which includes an example.

Comment: writing my own wrapper class around dynamo methods and then mocking that class helped to me solve this issue.